# Constant loss and accuracy in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation

I am training a model whose output and ground truth should be binary. It's an inception based two stream models. Inception architecture is used as an encoder and for decoder a custom based model is designed consisting of conv layers, batch normalization, up sampling and using tanh as non linearity.I have tried with relu but still no result.

Model is initializing at different values but not updating. My model's forward function is:

```
    def forward(self, inp):
        # Preprocessing
        out = self.conv3d_1a_7x7(inp)
        skip1 = out
        out = self.maxPool3d_2a_3x3(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.conv3d_2b_1x1(out)
        out = self.conv3d_2c_3x3(out)
        out = self.maxPool3d_3a_3x3(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.mixed_3b(out)
        skip2 = out
        out = self.mixed_3c(out)
        out = self.maxPool3d_4a_3x3(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.mixed_4b(out)
        
        out = self.mixed_4c(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.mixed_4d(out)
        skip3 = out
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.mixed_4e(out)
        out = self.mixed_4f(out)
        out = self.maxPool3d_5a_2x2(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.mixed_5b(out)
        out = self.mixed_5c(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)

        out = self.tconv6(out, skip1,skip2,skip3)
 
        out = self.sigmoid(out)
        print("Before permutation", out.shape)
        out = out.permute(0,1,3,4,2)
        out_logits = out
        return out, out_logits
```

My train function is:

```
misc,out_logits[stream] = models[stream](data[stream])
out_softmax = torch.nn.functional.softmax(out_logits[stream], 1).requires_grad_()
val, preds = torch.max(out_logits[stream].data, 1)
preds = preds.to(device, dtype=torch.float)
gt = torch.round(gt)
gt_avg = torch.mean(gt)
gt[gt>gt_avg] = 1
gt[gt<=gt_avg] = 0
out_logits[stream] = out_logits[stream].squeeze(1)
losses[stream] = criterion(preds.cpu(), gt.cpu()).requires_grad_()
if phase == 'train':
   optimizers[stream].zero_grad()
   losses[stream].backward(retain_graph=True)
   optimizers[stream].step()
running_losses[stream] += losses[stream].item() * data[stream].shape[0]
running_corrects[stream] += torch.sum(val.cpu() == gt_c.data.cpu()).item()
correct_t = torch.sum(preds==gt_c).item()
total_t = gt_c.shape[0]*gt_c.shape[1]*gt_c.shape[2]*gt_c.shape[3]
acc_epc = 100*correct_t/total_t
for scheduler in schedulers.values():
    scheduler.step()
```

My loss and accuracy is always constant shown here[image: constant loss and accuracy]

I have tried using different optimizers like SGD, Adam , RMSprop. Furthermore, I have tried tuning the hyperparameters but model is not converging. What am I missing?

Comment: You should look at how you defined your optimizers if it's not updating.

Answer (score 0):

You send the wrong variable into loss fuction if you are doing crossentropy. Change `preds` to `out_logits[stream]` and there's no need to do `.cpu()` and `require_grad()`.

```py
losses[stream] = criterion(out_logits[stream], gt)
```

Also, you performed argmax for `preds`. It's not differentiable regardless the loss function you used.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing it out. I tried it my loss is in range of 22.84 22.80, 22.88 and not converging. I am using SGD optimizer by changing hyper-parameters: lr in range of e-5 to e-8 and momentum between 0.5 to 2.

Comment: The learning rate is too small. You can try Adam with default lr.